# Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist in new react native project

Tags: react-native, cfbundleidentifier

I created a new project with the command **react-native init LocationExample --version 0.57.7**

It created a project named *LocationExample* but when I further went into project folder and ran the command **react-native run-ios**.

This gave an error stating  **Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist**

I have tried removing the build folder by running command **rm -rf ios/build** and also tried removing the mode modules by **rm -rf node_modules**. After which i ran **yarn** command to install the node_modules again but, this had no effect.

**Edit1:**

```
/Users/apple/React Native/LocationExample/node_modules/react-native/scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh: line 56: /Users/apple/React/ios-configure-glog.sh: No such file or directory
Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

Also this error

```
'glog/logging.h' file not found
```

**Expected:** App should be installed and should run successfully.

**Actual:** App is not installed and states the error of BundleIdentifier.

Answer (score 0):

Build it in `Xcode`. If the build is successful then run it in `Xcode` using `Cmd+R`

**EDIT**

Try this

1- Changing the bundle identifier.

2- Adding package:

`yarn add @babel/runtime`

3-

`watchman watch-del-all`

4- Removing the build:

`rm -rf ios/build`

5-

`sed -i '' '/DevelopmentTeam = V9WTTPBFK9/d;/DEVELOPMENT_TEAM/d;/ProvisioningStyle = Automatic/d' ./node_modules/react-native/React/React.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`

6-

`react-native start --reset-cache`

7-

`react-native run-ios`

Comment: This did not help me at all Please can you help me out i have updated the build issue